# Stopping MediaPlayer before playing again isn't working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I have a ListView with some items and each item plays a certain sound. This is the code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
            try {
                player.setDataSource(externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + recordedFilesArray.get(arg2) + ".mp3");
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

If I click an item and it starts playing and then click another item before the one I clicked before has finished playing, the MediaPlayer will just play both sounds at the same time. How do I get my MediaPlayer to stop() playing the previous sound and start playing the new sound if I have clicked the item before it stopped playing?

I tried adding player.Stop() before try, so that everytime I click an item, the MediaPlayer stops before setting a new source and starting again, but that just stops the previous sound and won't play the new sound.

I also tried adding IF statement, like this:

```
if (!player.isPlaying()){
//normally start the player
}
else if (player.isPlaying()){
//stop it before starting it again
}
```

I'd copy my actual code but I already deleted it since it didn't work. It also just stopped the previous sound and didn't play the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your player after stopping song.

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
        try {
             if (player!=null && player.isPlaying())
              {                     
               player.stop();
               player.reset();
              }

            player.setDataSource(externalStoragePath +     "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + recordedFilesArray.get(arg2) + ".mp3");
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setDataSource()` in the idle state. So you have to call `reset()` before calling `setDateSource()`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + recordedFilesArray.get(arg2) + ".mp3");
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
        try {
            stopPlaying();
            initializeMediaPlayer(externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + recordedFilesArray.get(arg2) + ".mp3");
            startPlaying();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});



private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player!=null && player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer(String path) {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(path);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    try {
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(player!=null)
            player.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to reuse `MediaPlayer`, you must call `reset()` before setting new `dataSource`. One more thing, you should not call `prepare()` in UI thread, it may cause `ANR` error. You would rather call `prepareAsync()` function.